OData Parser, Problem with Substring function
i am writing an OData parser and I am struggling with the substring function.
I want to parse the query 'substring(Location_Code, 5) eq 10', but he throws an error by number 5 inside the substring function. The problem is the lexerfunction 'SUBSTRING LBR PROPERTY KMA INT RBR', because if I change INT to VALUE it works. But the substring function accepts only in the terms of the odata definition integer values. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?
Input:
substring(Location_Code, 5) eq 10

Grammar:
grammar Filter;

filter: expression+ EOF ;

expression
    : PROPERTY operator
    | function operator
    ;
 
operator
    : CMP VALUE
    ;

function

    : SUBSTRING LBR PROPERTY KMA INT RBR
    ;    

functionParam: (VALUE (KMA VALUE)*);
       
VALUE
     : TRUE
     | FALSE
     | INT
     | FLOAT
     | STRING
     | NULL
     ;
    
LBR : '(';
RBR : ')';
KMA: ',';

SUBSTRING: S U B S T R I N G;

CMP 
    : E Q
    | L T
    | G T
    | G E
    | L E
    | N E
    ;
    
NOT: N O T;

NULL: N U L L;
    
PROPERTY
 : ALLOWED_CHARACTERS+ ('.' ALLOWED_CHARACTERS+)*
 ;

ALLOWED_CHARACTERS : [a-zA-Z0-9_-];

TRUE
 : 'true'
 ;

FALSE
 : 'false'
 ;

STRING
 : '\'' (~['\r\n] | '\'\'')* '\''
 ;

INT
 : DIGIT+
 ;

FLOAT
 : DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT*
 | '.' DIGIT+
 ;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];

A: [aA];
B: [bB];
C: [cC];
D: [dD];
E: [eE];
F: [fF];
G: [gG];
H: [hH];
I: [iI];
J: [jJ];
K: [kK];
L: [lL];
M: [mM];
N: [nN];
O: [oO];
P: [pP];
Q: [qQ];
R: [rR];
S: [sS];
T: [tT];
U: [uU];
V: [vV];
W: [wW];
X: [xX];
Y: [yY];
Z: [zZ];

SPACE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;
 


(1) Lexers are not "guided" or "influenced" by the parser (i.e., assume the lexer gathers all tokens before the parser even gets going). (2) The lexer rule with the longest string matches above all. (3) If two or more lexer rules match input with the same length, the first lexer rule listed in the grammar "wins". (4) String literals in a combined grammar are converted internally to lexer rules and prioritized over explicit lexer rules you wrote. (5) Always print the tokens, reset() the lexer before parsing. INT and VALUE match "10", but  VALUE wins because it occurs before INT.

very strange. I changed it temporary to string. Then I implemented additionally parser rules for additional functions. And now, I tested it again and now it works.
Thank's for your tips, I will take note of it and improve my grammar.
